# EclipseEnvironmentInfo class is unavailable in osgi bundle 3.10 onwards

Tags: eclipse, osgi

I'm using the EclipseEnvironmentInfo.getDefault().getCommandLineArgs() to get the command line arguements passed.

In the latest osgi from version 3.10 onwards this class and method is unavailable.

Can someone tell me what is the equivalent to this in the latest osgi jar?

Answer (score 1):

It's `EquinoxConfiguration`, however that is an internal class so I wouldn't recommend using it.

`Platform.getCommandLineArgs()` is a public method.

Alternatively you can get the EnvironmentInfo implementation from the OSGi service (code taken from `org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.Activator`):

```
BundleContext bc = ...;
ServiceReference infoRef = bc.getServiceReference(EnvironmentInfo.class.getName());
EnvironmentInfo envInfo = (EnvironmentInfo) bc.getService(infoRef);
bc.ungetService(infoRef);
```